# How to modify dataframe based on some condition and selecting last 3 rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `dataframe` that looks likes this

```
    a   b   c
0  222  34  23
1  333  31  11
2  444  16  21
3  555  32  22
4  666  33  27
5  777  35  11
```

I need to check if column `C` is greater than some value(mean of something else) in the last 3 `rows` than affect `old value → new value (mean)`

for example, in column "C" row 5 I will get 11 → 22

there is what I tried but it breeds an error

```
import pandas as pd

mean=22
# List of Tuples
matrix = [(222, 34, 23),
(333, 31, 11),
(444, 16, 21),
(555, 32, 22),
(666, 33, 27),
(777, 35, 11)
]
# Create a DataFrame object
df = pd.DataFrame(matrix, columns=list('abc'))
print(df)
df.iloc[-3:].loc[df["c"] < mean, "c"] = pd.Series(map(lambda x: str(x)+" → "+ str(mean), df.iloc[-3:].loc[df["c"] < mean, "c"]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create another mask for testing last 3 index values with [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html), so no `iloc` is necessary and processing only matched rows by mask:

```
mean=22
mask = (df["c"] < mean) & df.index.isin(df.index[-3:])
df.loc[mask, "c"] = df.loc[mask, "c"].astype(str) +" → "+ str(mean)
print (df)

     a   b        c
0  222  34       23
1  333  31       11
2  444  16       21
3  555  32       22
4  666  33       27
5  777  35  11 → 22
```

To replace `mean` by mask, the solution is simplier:

```
mean=22
mask = (df["c"] < mean) & df.index.isin(df.index[-3:])
df.loc[mask, "c"] = mean
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a copy of the last 3 lines, process that copy and then report the new value into the initial dataframe:

```
df1 = df.iloc[-3:].copy()            # use copy to be allowed to modify the values
df1.loc[df1.c < mean, 'c'] = mean    # process the copy
df.loc[df1.index, 'c'] = df1['c']    # copy back into the original dataframe
```

which gives:

```
     a   b   c
0  222  34  23
1  333  31  11
2  444  16  21
3  555  32  22
4  666  33  27
5  777  35  22
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not try to mimic the exact example but you are able to replace any value in the dataframe based on `iloc` and `loc` which people use to overlook when start using pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

# intialise data of lists.
txt_data = '''a,b,c
222,34,23
333,31,11
444,16,21
555,32,22
666,33,27
777,35,11'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(txt_data))
# pick the value we want to replace
any_value = 21
# pick the mean value
mean_value = 12
# -3 means last 3 rows based on row index, 2 means last column based on column index
# apply a lambda function to change the value
df.iloc[-3:, 2] = df.iloc[-3:, 2].apply(lambda x: any_value if x > mean_value else x)
```